# Bijection between hom sets of $k$ - algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

Let $R:= k[x_1,\ldots,x_r]$, $S:= k[x_{r+1},\ldots,x_{r+s}]$ and $Q:= k[x_1,\ldots,x_{r+s}]$. Let $I \subseteq R$ and $J \subseteq S$ be ideals. I have in texts in algebraic geometry that for any $k$ - algebra $T$, there is a bijection

$$\operatorname{Hom}(R/I,T) \times \operatorname{Hom}(S/J,T) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(Q/(I,J),T).$$

Now I understand that for any pair $(f,g)$ on the left hand side I can an element on the right hand side: Just send the generators  $x_1,\ldots,x_r \pmod{I+J}$ to $f(x_1 \mod I), \ldots, f(x_r \mod{I})$. Similarly for $g$. However I fail to see how given an element on the right hand side, we get a pair on the left. The thing is given $h : Q/(I,J) \to T$, I can't just say that I want $x_1 \mod I$ to go to $h(x_1 \mod{I+J})$ because this may not be well - defined. How is this bijection actually established?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier for you to do the general case, where for any $k$-algebras $A, B$ there is a natural isomorphism $Hom(A, -) \times Hom(B, -) \simeq Hom(A \otimes _{k} B, -)$? This specializes to exactly what you're after, but might force you to ignore the irrelevant details.

Comment: @PiotrPstragowski I know that isomorphism already.

Comment: @Andrew Sorry, I made some typos above. I have corrected my question now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\hom(R/I,T) \subseteq T^r$ contains the $T$-valued solutions to the polynomials in $I$, and similarily $\hom(S/J,T) \subseteq T^s$ contains the $T$-valued solutions to the polynomials in $J$. Hence, $\hom(R/I,T) \times \hom(S/J,T) \subseteq T^{r+s}$ contains the $T$-valued solutions to the polynomials in $I$ and in $J$, embedded into $Q$. So this equals $\hom(Q/(I,J),T)$.

By the way, this bijection is another way of saying that $R/I \otimes_k S/J = Q/(I,J)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though can you elaborate on how given a map on the right hand side( in my question above) we obtain one on the left?

Comment: This is induced via pullback of the homomorphisms $R/I \to Q/(I,J)$ and $T/J \to Q/(I,J)$ sending $[x_j]$ to $[x_j]$.